# How do I escape from the bottom of the ocean?

Tags: starbound

I dove to the bottom of the ocean and made a little pocket of air for myself.  Then I started digging for stuff.  Now that my bag is full, I want to get back to the surface so I can teleport to my ship, but I can't seem to swim fast enough to the surface, how can I get back to the surface easily?  Is there anything that can help me with this in the future?  (Other than a teleporter)

Comment: I don't quite understand - why can't you just swim up (hold space)?

Comment: @PrivatePansy I run out of air before I reach surface, and also its a ocean of acid :P

Comment: Could you edge around the bottom of the ocean by destroying and replacing blocks until you reach the edge of the ocean and then go up the side?

Comment: The thing that confuses me is that sinking is slower than swimming up, so I don't see how you managed to get to the bottom if you can't get up again.

Comment: @PrivatePansy lots of healing items :P

Comment: @Riftcaster In Starbound the islands "float" on top of the ocean, and since the world wraps around, the seabed is one long continuous piece with no end, so this won't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to build a tunnel of solid blocks.

To do this, stand just under the Ocean floor, and use your Matter Manipulator to place a 4xN column background tiles directly above you. Once you've placed the background tiles, place foreground tiles in the same place. Then, hollow out your column (being careful not to breach the ocean as you do so!)

Placing the foreground blocks will destroy the liquid, and placing the background blocks will prevent the ocean (which is infinite) from filling the space back in.

Comment: This was the method I eventually used since I couldn't think of any other way.

Comment: At this point it might be wise to consider committing suicide, especially if you're playing on Casual

Comment: @PrivatePansy I'm not, otherwise i'd just teleport back to my ship.

Answer (score 2):

Sable Dreamer already explained how to get out of this mess when you are already in it. But I would like to answer the question about how to prevent this mess from occurring in the first place.

Next time you want to go diving, equip an EPP unit on your back. It doesn't just provide air on airless moons and asteroid fields but also when under water. When you would like to explore the poison oceans of toxic planets (you maniac), craft a lot of [poison antidote](http://starbounder.org/Poison_Antidote) at your Apothecary / Medical Station. It makes you immune to the poisoned status effect for 5 minutes when consumed, so you can safely swim in them (it doesn't help against the acid rain on the surface, though).

Comment: I didn't know about the antidote, that's super useful.  Thanks

Comment: Another thing to do: carry around a teleporter. I find them useful whenever I'm deep underground and don't want to dig my way back up (or am worried about dying and then having to make my way back down to wherever I ended up).